# Unit testing several messages in Bot Framework using Chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, botframework, chai

I'm covering my chatbot (built with Bot Framework) by unit tests using Chai. In one case, the bot responds to a user by 2 messages. I want to check that both messages are correct. The only I found for this test not to fail is this:

```
bot.on('send', (message) => {
        expect(message.text).to.satisfy(function(text) {
            if (text === message1 || text === message2 ) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });


    });

done();
```

As I can see through the test, the callback happens twice and the test passes when the bot functions correctly; however, the test doesn't really check whether 2 different messages were returned in correct order.

Is there any way to do this using Chai's `expect` or other tools?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a tool for this, because it seems like a very specific problem. What you could do is:

```
let messages = [message1, message2]
let index = 0
bot.on('send', (message) => {
    expect(message.text).toBe(messages[index++]);
});

done();
```

And I'm not sure about the `done()` part. You might want to call it when `index === messages.length`

Answer (score 1):

If you create a spy for callback function using sinon for example, you can assert if the first call for callback was with message1 and second call was with message 2.
spy.firstCall.calledWith(message1);
spy.secondCall.calledWith(message2);
You can read more here, if you would like - http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.0.1/spies/